# How to update the last row of a listview android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am creating a chat app. As I get new chat from server I am updating the list by adding a last row to the list. But once I am sending a message I adds it to the list. When message is send I am getting success response from the server. I need to update the success message in the last row of the list without adding a new row.

I am pasting block of code from the adapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (type == TYPE_MESSAGE) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_view, null);
        if(msg.equals("Seen")) {
            // need to change the status here. Don't add new row
        }else if(msg.equals("Not Seen")) {
           // need to change the status here. Don't add new row     
        } else if(msg.equals("Received message")){
        // need to change the status here. Don't add new row     
    } else {
        // else add new row and add new chat message
    }
    return view;
}
```

Can anybody give me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Update adapter and call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
getListView().setSelection(adapter.getCount()-1);
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged does not work for update. Works for add/ delete.

Comment: It would be call after adapter have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listView.getChildAt(listview.getAdapter().getCount()-1)` - returned view last row.